# webApi parameters data-length

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How can I configurate WebApi Controller to read all data that passed in as a parameter?

Client:

```
  $.post(url,{id:aHugeData});
```

Controller:

```
 public class myController : ApiController
  {
   public List<string> Events(List<Event> id) //there must be 30 items, but I see 7
        {
            List<string> artists = new List<string>();
            foreach (Event e in id)
            {
                artists.AddRange(e.artists.artist);
            }
            artists = artists.Distinct().ToList();

            return artists;
        }
 }
```

in HttpContext I see that all data received.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wujZB.png "screenshot"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form Url Encoded Formatter doesn't want to read confoguration from
  httpRuntime maxRequestLength="80000000", so in global.asax:

```
  public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration conf)
    {
        conf.Formatters.FormUrlEncodedFormatter.ReadBufferSize = int.MaxValue/10;
    }
```