# Web Api max parameter length

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have a very simple dto

```
public class RisRequest
{
    public string APIKey { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And a nice easy web api

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage rad(RisRequest request)
```

99% of the time this works. but when I hit a request where the Message is longer than the norm (>100,000 characters, and 112kb) then this parameter is null. note the APIKey is still good, my RisRequest object isn't null, but only th eMessage parameter.

I did some googling and tried a bunch of options

as per [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229235/webapi-parameters-data-length) I tried setting the httpconfig buffer

```
config.Formatters.FormUrlEncodedFormatter.ReadBufferSize = int.MaxValue/10;
```

I tried the web.config options in [this link](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/)

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
   <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
   </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

and

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" />
</system.web>
```

and no luck with either. all other some suggest a variation of the same.
Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thank

Answer (score 1):

According to [Max Parameter length in MVC](http://forums.asp.net/t/1842984.aspx?Max%20Parameter%20length%20in%20MVC)

this is a windows restriction. in your url, the parameter is part of the path. windows restricts a path segments length.

you should change `UrlSegmentMaxLength` in regedit.

create a `DWORD` value in the following registery key

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`

`UrlSegmentMaxCount`

> Maximum number of URL path segments. If zero, the count bounded by the
>   maximum value of a ULONG.
>
> Valid value range 0 - 16,383